# Handle files in serializers Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a file field in serializer.py and i need to write a custom validation for file field.The code i have written is this:

class SendMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
     model=ChatMessages

def validate_file(self,attrs,source):
   file=attrs['file']
   messages=attrs['messages']
   if file and messages:
       raise serializers.ValidationError('You can select only one field')
   return  file
```

when i call this function is shows below errors:

```
TypeError at /chat-message/send/
string indices must be integers
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/chat-message/send/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
string indices must be integers
Exception Location: /home/something/projects/something/apps/chats/serializer.py in validate_file, line 13
Python Executable:  /home/something/Virtualenv/something/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ntech/projects/something',
 '/home/ntech/Virtualenv/something/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/ntech/Virtualenv/something/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ntech/Virtualenv/something/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ntech/Virtualenv/something/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/ntech/Virtualenv/something/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ntech/Virtualenv/something/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ntech/Virtualenv/something/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 2 Jan 2015 09:33:35 +0000
```

I need to check whether field as file or not,How do i check that,is there any alternate solution for getting file????

Comment: Please, show us all code of your serializer.

Comment: @zymud i have updated.this is code in serializers.py

Comment: Thanks, please tell me what version of django rest framework are you using?

Comment: @zymud am using djangorestframework==2.4.4

Comment: Currently I see only one mistake - method `validate_file` has to return `attrs`(not `file`). But I don't think that it causes your exception. Please show me value of `attrs` variable before exception (you can use breakpoint or just print it).

Comment: @zymud attrs['file'] field is a file field and attrs['messages'] this is a textfield.For first case it is expecting string,but its getting a file.I think beacause of this reason error is showing.attrs['file'] is showing nothing and it is showing exception here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68079/discussion-between-zymud-and-vishnu).